# Orientdb 3.0.26 OETL JDBC oracle Driver not found

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2, orientdb-2.1, orientdb-etl, orientdb3.0

Trying to Import data from an oracle database into a OrientDB graph using OETL.

I've noticed that on `jdbc-drivers.json` the URL for oracle driver is not working

```
{
  "Oracle": {
    "className": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
     ## "className": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
    "url": "http://svn.ets.berkeley.edu/nexus/content/repositories/myberkeley/com/oracle/ojdbc7/12.1.0.1/ojdbc7-12.1.0.1.jar",
    "version": "7-12.1.0.1",
    "format": [
      "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<HOST>:<PORT>:<SID>"
    ]
  },
```

So i replace it with both

```
"url": "https://github.com/MHTaleb/ojdbc7/raw/master/ojdbc7.jar",
```

and also localy with

```
"url": "C:\Users\sviu\Desktop\orientdb-3.0.26\ojdbc7.jar",
```

I'm  using the following configuration

```
{
  "config": {
    "log": "error"
  },
  "extractor" : {
    "jdbc": { 
              "driver": "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
              ## "driver": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
              "url": "jdbc:oracle:thin:@URL:1521:SID",
              "userName": "DB_OWNER",
              "userPassword": "DBPWD",
              "query": "select * from LOT" }
  },
  "transformers" : [
   { "vertex": { "class": "Lot"} }
  ],
  "loader" : {
    "orientdb": {
      "dbURL": "plocal:../databases/LDS",
      "dbUser": "admin",
      "dbPassword": "admin",
      "dbAutoCreate": true,
    "dbType": "graph"
    }
  }
}
```

Tried both driver names and classname change combination in `jdbc-drivers.json` and `lots.json`

Always getting driver not found.

```
C:\Users\sviu\Desktop\orientdb-3.0.26\bin>oetl.bat lots.json
OrientDB etl v.3.0.26 - Veloce (build 39bd95d70410374ab1cf6770ef2feca26145b04f, branch 3.0.x) https://www.orientdb.com
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: Error on creating ETL processor
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessorConfigurator.parse(OETLProcessorConfigurator.java:153)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessorConfigurator.parseConfigAndParameters(OETLProcessorConfigurator.java:92)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.main(OETLProcessor.java:116)
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: [JDBC extractor] JDBC Driver oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver not found
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.extractor.OETLJDBCExtractor.configure(OETLJDBCExtractor.java:69)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessorConfigurator.configureComponent(OETLProcessorConfigurator.java:158)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessorConfigurator.configureExtractor(OETLProcessorConfigurator.java:216)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessorConfigurator.parse(OETLProcessorConfigurator.java:115)
        ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.extractor.OETLJDBCExtractor.configure(OETLJDBCExtractor.java:67)
    ... 5 more
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

BR

Comment: AFAIK OETL from the command line doesn't use the jdbc-drivers.json. Just copy the driver in the lib folder of orient, or where there are all the other jars if lib doesn't exist.

Comment: That fixed  it indeed. Thank you tons.